# There is a way to send json string or even JSONObject to POSTMAN without a slash before every double quote?

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, postman

After alot of research i knew that JAVA does that internally. Tried to replace the slashes with empty string .Also tried to use some libraries to parse String to JSONObject But Same result, A slash before every double qoute..

Request To POSTMAN:

```
    {
        "MTI": "0100",
        "2": "4655206331051889",
        "3": "000000",
        "4": "000000012300",
        "7": "0321054133",
        "11": "001205",
        "14": "0325",
        "18": "5399",
        "22": "022",
        "25": "00",
        "35": "2312312332",
        "37": "206305000014",
        "41": "29110001",
        "42": "1001001",
        "49": "840",
        "transactionid": "12",
        "co-ordinates": "3042304,293572945"
    }
```

Code:

```
        StringBuilder transactionReq = new StringBuilder();
              for (Object o : responseMessage.getChildren().keySet()) {
                int key = (Integer) o;
        
                // The Transaction Request Body that has been Received in JSON Format.
                transactionReq
                    .append('"')
                    .append(key)
                    .append('"')
                    .append(" : ")
                    .append('"')
                    .append(responseMessage.getValue(key))
                    .append('"')
                    .append(" ,");
              }
              transactionReq
                  .insert(0, "{")
                  .deleteCharAt(transactionReq.length() - 1)
                  .deleteCharAt(transactionReq.length() - 1)
                  .insert(transactionReq.length(), "}");
              response.setMessage(transactionReq.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
    System.out.println(transactionReq.toString());
```

Console:

```
    {
        "message": "{"0" : "0110" ,"1" : "4655206331051889" ,"3" : "000000" ,"4" : "000000012300" ,"6" : "000000000012" ,"7" : "0321054133" ,"11" : "001205" ,"14" : "0325" ,"18" : "5399" ,"22" : "022" ,"25" : "00" ,"35" : "2312312332" ,"37" : "549684      " ,"38" : "84738 " ,"39" : "00" ,"41" : "29110001" ,"42" : "1001001        " ,"49" : "840" ,"57" : "3042304" ,"58" : "293572945"}"
    }
```

Response From POSTMAN:

```
    {
    "message": "{\"0\" : \"0110\" ,\"2\" : \"4655206331051889\" ,\"3\" : \"000000\" ,\"4\" : \"000000012300\" ,\"6\" : \"000000000012\" ,\"7\" : \"0321054133\" ,\"11\" : \"001205\" ,\"14\" : \"0325\" ,\"18\" : \"5399\" ,\"22\" : \"022\" ,\"25\" : \"00\" ,\"35\" : \"2312312332\" ,\"37\" : \"549684      \" ,\"38\" : \"84738 \" ,\"39\" : \"00\" ,\"41\" : \"29110001\" ,\"42\" : \"1001001        \" ,\"49\" : \"840\" ,\"57\" : \"3042304\" ,\"58\" : \"293572945\"}"
    }
```

*The Output in the console proves that iam sending a right json request..
But the response the shows in postman says the opposite..
**Happy to hear any Explanation...
Thanks in Advance***

Comment: May you please explain what you are trying to achieve and what should be the output?

Comment: Edited the Question to be crystal-clear..Please Refer to it if you happy to help.

Comment: How the response sending code looks like? are you using spring or servlet or any other way? Because string cannot have `"` that's why escape character is used `\\` to parse it.

Comment: Iam using Spring Boot... yeah i knew that java does that internally .. So what am supposed to do ?

Comment: If you are using spring then if you just return the string, spring will convert it into JSON and the client will receive JSON only, whether you use postman or any other, if you are not receiving it a JSON then you must post the the controller side, so that we know you are not doing any mistakes over there.

Comment: This is the controller side

Comment: What is the response object?

Comment: I have  ModelApiResponse that i use it as a prototype for all my response objects

Comment: See if you have string with double quotes, it will have escape characters and they won't be removed and the escape characters are not printed to the console, hence your console showing fine, but it will all depend how you are returning from controller, if it is a String it would be correct JSON, but I think, you are returning object which has some property assigned with this JSON string, so that would come as String only with escapre character included because its a string.

Comment: Nice explanation so what should i do ?

Comment: If this is the object you are using for every API response then you have very less choices and it depends on your use case as well, if you can frame your question with little more info like what you are trying to achieve and do you have more such APIs, then may be someone can help.

Comment: Iam sending a ISO Message Fields to a jpos-based project and returning the response back in json

Comment: If you can create small DTOs for every such API then use those DTOs instead of string

Comment: And in the ModelApiResponse i change the parameter String Message to a DTO Class ?

Comment: No Slashes before every double quote will present ?

Comment: No, with DTO slashes will not come, because Spring will do the part you are doing manually

Comment: Ok man Thank to you alot

Comment: First try and thank me later :)

Comment: I will try it but logically you r right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s built in java, Java treats Strings that way , So i used a DTO To avoid that